# dynamic where clause entity framework 3.5

Tags: c#, linq, entity

I am new to entity framework.
I need to develop a Linq query based on Orders and Customers.

for eg: string firstName can have any of the three values

1) null
2) Joe
3) like %Joe%'

simailary i need to develop for lastname

My current query is like this

```
                using (NorthwindEntities ent = new NorthwindEntities())
                {
                    var UsersList = ent.User.Include("Orders").
                                Include("OrderDetails").
                                Include("OrderDetails.Products").
                               .Where(o => (firstName== null || o.firstName== firstName||o.firstName.Contains(firstName)) 
&& (LastName== null || o.LastName== LastName ||o.LastName.contains(LastName) ) 

    }
```

Is my query is correct. Is any other better option to write linq entity query.

Thanks

Comment: If you are new to Entity FrameWork. Dont go with EF 1.0, Which comes with .net 3.5 SP1. Which having some issue. you with next generation EF 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add conditions to a Queryable object.  The conditions will build up until the data query is executed.

```
var UsersList = ent.User.Include("Orders")
               .Include("OrderDetails")
               .Include("OrderDetails.Products");

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
   UsersList = UsersList.Where( o => o.firstName.Contains(firstName));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
   UsersList = UsersList.Where( o => o.LastName.Contains(LastName));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can split your query in parts, its somewhat nicer then:

```
var UsersList = ent.User.Include("Orders")
                        .Include("OrderDetails")
                        .Include("OrderDetails.Products");

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName));
   UsersList = UsersList.Where( o => o.firstName.Contains(firstName));

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName));
   UsersList = UsersList.Where( o => o.lastName.Contains(lastName))
```

Also the check `o.firstName == firstName` is redundant, the `Contains(firstName)` part is sufficient (same for lastName).

Comment: yes, since you are only defining the query and its not executing yet, splitting it into logical parts makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could build up your query in steps:

```
    using (NorthwindEntities ent = new NorthwindEntities())
    {
       var UsersList = ent.User.Include("Orders")
                .Include("OrderDetails")
                .Include("OrderDetails.Products");
       if (LastName != null)
          UserList = UserList.Where(o => o.LastName == LastName || o.LastName.contains(LastName));

       if (FirstName != null)
          UserList = UserList.Where(o => o.firstName== firstName||o.firstName.Contains(firstName);

       // etc
   }
```

The query won't execute until you do a ToList() or use it in a `foreach` or something like that.